# TravisCI - Not finding a pip package

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, travis-ci, python-unittest

I am running test script in TravisCI and installing requirements using **pip install -r requirements.txt**. However, even though the required package (distro) is installed and everything, it does not find distro when I run the test script. (I am testing for python3.4)

I have uploaded two photos, where the first one shows that the required package, distro is already installed and now located at the site-packages however, when I run the script, **it just does find it and raises an ImportError**

[Github repo here.](https://github.com/ibtehaz-shawon/Hacker-Playbook-Utility)

[image: Image 1 - Installing dependencies]
[image: Image 2 - ImportError]

Comment: The command is being executed with sudo and the pip is installed via the `travis` user.

Comment: Ya, thanks man. @MattSchuchard Finally passed, although thats not my intention to run the test script anyway.